# openssl create certificate and key

Tags: openssl

[OpenSSL v1.1.0f]

I am using the following command to create a self-signed certificate, for test purposes only:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 10000 -nodes
```

However I get the messages like this:

```
Can't open /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
140480609138432:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74:fopen('/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf','r')
140480609138432:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:81:
Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
..................................++
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................++
writing new private key to 'key.pem'
-----
unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config
problems making Certificate Request
140480609138432:error:0E06D06A:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no conf or environment variable:crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:272:
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: In which way have you installed openssl? sudo apt-get install libssl-dev?

Answer (score 7):

Normally openssl would use a default config but seems like you don't have it at the right place. You can also pass a config file as a command line parameter. Note the -config option.

```
openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 10000 -nodes
```

Comment: Thanks.  What should the openssl.cnf file contain, as a minimum?

Comment: The best source of information should be at [openssl doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/). You can also directly download [openssl.cnf](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/openssl.cnf) from github - this is probably the easiest way since you just need something for testing.

Comment: Damn, this command and using the`openssl.cnf` did not work for me. `20636:error:0E06D06A:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no conf or environment variable:crypto\conf\conf_lib.c:270:` Windows here